# Pycharm / Jetbrains product odd highlighting. Any idea what is being highlighted?

Tags: ide, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm having a weird problem in pycharm that I can't seem to work out.

Using the Darcula theme, I'm seeing some odd highlighting as seen in the below image

[image: example]

Any idea what it is?  I'm thinking I must have accidentally turned on some obscure tool, but I can't spot any rhyme or reason.

Comment: I'm guessing that is what the theme does to everything inside the tag <form>, you could try to check if that's the case and if is, change the theme to remove the background color for that specific tag :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a form, but does seem to highlighting any div contents, and then de-highlighting when it hits another element within.

Comment: There you go, you can now try to change the syntax theme to remove that background color from <div> elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason / somehow you have injected custom language (HTML?) into DIV (?) tags (the green background).

`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Language Injections` -- find and delete offending rule. It should have "Project" or "Global" in most right column (Scope) -- do not touch "Bundled" ones.

Alternatively -- <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> while having caret inside problematic place and choose "Uninject xxx" from popup menu. This will only disable that rule (which is still enough to make it work as before) .. but you better delete such wrong rule at some point later.

Comment: Absolutely the correct answer!  I have no idea how I managed to add it, but I guess I must have fat fingered it some how!